# store arabic in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation

I tried to store Arabic string in SQL 2008 database but it converted to " question mark " why ? and what should I do ?

Comment: Is it mysql database or my sql database?

Comment: sql 2008 database not my sql sorry for this syntax mistake

Comment: Were you trying to store the Arabic characters in columns of type `(var)char` or `n(var)char`?

Comment: nvarchar and varchar ? I do it by luck in other project but after I changed windows it didn't work

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You need to choose an Arabic collation for your varchar/char columns or use Unicode (nchar/nvarchar)

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
col1 VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI,
col2 VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS,
col3 NVARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(N'لا أتكلم العربية',N'لا أتكلم العربية',N'لا أتكلم العربية')
```

> Note the N before values in insert statement above.  If you do not mention it, system will treat the values as Varchar, not NVarchar.

```
SELECT * FROM #test
```

Returns

```
col1                           col2                           col3
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
?? ????? ???????               لا أتكلم العربية               لا أتكلم العربية
```

To see a list of Arabic collations use

```
SELECT name, description 
FROM fn_helpcollations() 
WHERE name LIKE 'Arabic%'
```

Comment: You are AWESOME !! Appreciate it much !! I am going to add your answer to my blog.

Comment: using Unicode data types like (nchar/nvarchar) was very enough , thank you very much Martin

Comment: I used nvarchar and i still get ?.? output from 'د.إ'

Comment: @Sam, You might have written something like UPDATE table SET column = 'العربية', instead of: UPDATE table SET column = N'العربية'... The difference is in the "N" placed before the start of the string to indicate that it is a unicode... That is, you have to specify that the string is unicode in addition to the column being unicode.

Comment: Thnks but what about storing these 3 columns on the disk.? How much **One character** in these 3 columns   take space on disk?

Answer (score 19):

All of what you have to do is to make sure that

the `column Data type` is `nvarchar()`

[image]

after that I inserted Arabic with no problems

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can change the collation on the database level instead of changing for each column in the database:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE TestDB
COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI;
GO
```

Answer (score 6):

insert into table (column) values (**N**'xxx').)

You should put N before string to make it **unicode**

Answer (score 5):

Add **'N'** before every value.
example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(N'aaaaaaaaa',N'ששששששששששששש',N'aaaaaaaaaaa',N'ششششششششششش')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:
the column Data type is `nvarchar()`

```
INSERT INTO CompanyMaster values(N'" + txtCompNameAR.Text + "',N'" + txtCompAddressAR.Text + "','" + txtPh.Text + "')
```

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31244917/7951774)  is helpful but work here's what works for me in all cases

```
ALTER DATABASE [database] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 
GO 

ALTER DATABASE [database] COLLATE ARABIC_CI_AS; 
GO 

ALTER DATABASE [database] SET MULTI_USER; 
GO
```

Update: eventually I have to change datatype varchar to nvarchar in my project

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for Thanks

Answer (score 1):

make sure all your tables and `varchar` columns have the collation of `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` is not a valid SQL Server 2008 collation

Answer (score -7):

Iti is easy to store Arabic string in Oracle. Use this code:

```
declare @P_CUSTOMER_NAME  nchar(50) 
set @P_CUSTOMER_NAME2=N'أختبار'
```

The above will save in Oracle just fine.

Comment: Why does your answer mention Oracle?