# Arabic characters is appearing as ??? when using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, arabic

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and I am using SSIS to import date from another server (SQL 2005) to  my production server. When I import Arabic characters, it is appearing as question marks while it is working on test environment.

I checked all the settings and collations for the server, DB, tables and columns. everything is identical. I believe that it is not a matter of coding since it is working on test and I copied the same SSIS package to be used on production.

The source columns have NVARCHAR as datatype while the destination have VARCHAR. I created a simple query to select the data from the source and insert it to destination and it is working without any problem but when I am using SSIS to import the date, it is not working.

Any idea?

Comment: Any reason for not using NVARCHAR for destination DB?

Comment: I think this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560173/store-arabic-in-sql-database

Comment: Where is it appearing as ?? - in your client app? in a browser? in SSMS?

Comment: This is an old DB and it was working on different server as well on test environment. Question marks are coming in the SQL browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue and breaking my head to find a workaround. After several trial and error methods, the below step worked for me:

#### Issue

The driver interprets the data from Oracle DB as `DT_STR` type and does not support Arabic characters. To solve this we need the driver to read the data as `DT_WSTR` type.

#### Solution

So the solution is we need to make SSIS engine to read the data as `DT_WSTR` and not `DT_STR`.

#### VS Solution

I was using `Microsoft OLE DB provider for Oracle` as a provider in connection manager and was facing this error.

VS provides another driver to connect to Oracle DB, `Oracle Provider for OLE DB`. This driver reads the data in `DT_WSTR` format.

When I created the data source using the `Oracle Provider for OLE DB` the data is being read in `DT_WSTR` format and successfully pushed to the destination in the same character as in the source.

[image]