# How to store Arabic in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, collation

I am trying to store Arabic-strings in my database. it is working fine by using `COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS` but some of Arabic records are missing some Arabic-alphabets. i have tried    with some other sollate with but result as same. how to fix it ?
**table structure** :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ayyat_Translation_Language_old_20131209] (
    [Ayat_Translation_Language_ID] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Translation_Laanguage_ID]     INT            NULL,
    [Juz_ID]                       INT            NULL,
    [Surah_ID]                     INT            NOT NULL,
    [Ayat_Description]             VARCHAR (2000) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS NOT NULL
)
```

**insertion code :**

```
 string query = "insert into Ayyat_Translation_Language_old_20131209 values(null,null," + surah + ",N'" + verse + "')"; where verse contains Arabic contents.
```

and it stores data like this (with question-marks) :

```
?بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَ?نِ الرَّحِيمِ
```

i have read that link : [store arabic in SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560173/store-arabic-in-sql-database)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To store unicode string data, use `NVARCHAR(2000)` rather than `VARCHAR(2000)` for column `[Ayat_Description]`

Ref.: [nchar and nvarchar](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

All of what you have to do is to make sure that

the `column Data type` is `nvarchar()`

[image]

after that I inserted Arabic with no problems even with `Tashkeel`

[image]

this in `SQl server management studio 2012`

Answer (score 1):

It may help

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ayyat_Translation_Language_old_20131209] (
    [Ayat_Translation_Language_ID] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Translation_Laanguage_ID]     INT            NULL,
    [Juz_ID]                       INT            NULL,
    [Surah_ID]                     INT            NOT NULL,
    [Ayat_Description]             NVARCHAR (2000) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

use `arabic collation` or `use unicode(nvarchar(max))`

This is a Example table For your answer :

```
CREATE TABLE #t11
        (

        column1 NVARCHAR(100) 

        )
        INSERT INTO #t11 VALUES(N'لا أتكلم العربية')

        SELECT * FROM #t11
```

## [fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57287/1)