# Transform SQL Server text from French to Arabic

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I have an existing SQL Server database where text is stored in Arabic. The default database collation is `FRENCH_CI_AS`, but the application uses Arabic. Displaying the data with ASP is not a problem, but I want to create a new database using `UTF-8`!

Text sample as it's stored in database :

> ØªØ±Ø£Ø³ ÙˆØ²ÙŠØ± Ø§Ù„Ø³ÙƒÙ† ÙˆØ§Ù„Ø¹Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù† ÙˆÙˆØ²ÙŠØ± Ø§Ù„Ø£Ø´ØºØ§Ù„ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ù…ÙˆÙ…ÙŠØ© Ù„Ù„Ø¬Ù†Ø© Ø§Ù„ØªÙ‚Ù†ÙŠØ© Ù„Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù‚Ø¨Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ù†Ø§Ø¡

[image]

How I can transform text to get clear Arabic text in the database ?

Is there a solution using Excel? http://en.file-upload.net/download-10245297/test.xls.html

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3561385/1880431

Comment: I'm sorry but the text is already distorted in an existing database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share a little java project (*with dependencies*).
This project loads table data first and formats strings. The generated EXCEL worksheet can now imported using SSMS.

Java solution :

```
String charabia = "ØªØ±Ø£Ø³ ÙˆØ²ÙŠØ± Ø§Ù„Ø³ÙƒÙ† ÙˆØ§Ù„Ø¹Ù…Ø±" ;
try {
     String utf8String = new String(charabia.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
}
```

My project download link : [here](http://en.file-upload.net/download-10260241/charabia.zip.html)

Answer (score 2):

first of all use **nvarchar()** for type of Data in your Tables then when inserting data into your tabel insert like this

```
string Query="insert into tablename(columnName) values(N'value')...";
```

Comment: i save Date in Kurdish or Persian Languages(need UTF-8) into my database tables and it works good.but dont forget putting an **N** before value it allows you save unicode data

Comment: I'm sorry but the text is already distorted in an existing database

Comment: you mean that you are reading some distorted data from another table?

Comment: yes. I have done this but by developing an application

Answer (score 0):

The strings need to be stored in the database as NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR.  This allows the database to store UTF16 encoded strings instead of ASCII with a CodePage.  Of course this will double the amount of storage needed for the database.

From the screen shot it looks like the string is UTF8 being displayed as if it was ASCII and there does not appear to be a way to tell SQL this detail.