# update a varchar column with arabic names in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update a `varchar` column with `Arabic` names in SQL.

My table column `ArabicCode` is of type varchar. I don't want to change the type of the column. Is there another way to update the column with Arabic names. Now it's updating as `???`.

```
update myTable set  ArabicCode = `اسقف مستعار` where masterid = 2
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: No you can't do that with varchar datatype itself.

Comment: You need to use `nvarchar`

Comment: ok.Thank you.No other way ,are you sure?Anything related with collation?

Comment: Yes, you can use some arabic collation (if there is one!). However, it's very tricky - you need to make sure all your literal strings and parameters are in the proper collation, and it still means that your column has to have that collation (that is, you can't have two different collations in one column). `nvarchar` is just *much* simpler (make sure to use `N'ala'` literals rather than `'ala'`).

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate because you have specifically asked about VARCHAR, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3561385/1048425) should help. Either way you are going to need to alter your column.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you need to change the datatype from `varchar` to `nvarchar`

If you execute your update SQL query the data will be inserted as `??????` as the column type is `varchar` which does not allow to store any `Unicode data`.

Also make changes in your `Update` query as shown below -

```
update myTable set  ArabicCode = N`اسقف مستعار` where masterid = 2
```

To know difference check link- [varchar vs nvarchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

I suggest you to change your datatype to `Nvarchar`

Comment: Ok.Thanks for the quick response.But I cant change the type of the column , I'm getting error The index '_dta_index_mr001_17_1977058079__K9_K1_K8_3_5' is dependent on column 'code'.ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN code failed because one or more objects access this column.